# Using a HyperLinkField within a GridView to Pass a Date Value From One Page to Another

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I'm having a problem passing a date value from a `GridView` generated `HyperLinkField` to another page. Through some searching, I believe I'm using the correct syntax to generate the link, but whenever I try to bind a `date` to the `DataNavigateUrlFields` property, it won't create the hyper link. The method that I'm using does work when passing other fields.

This is the code I'm using.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
     DataNavigateUrlFields="DATE_REF,STUDENT_ID,ASSIGN_ID"
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Edit.aspx?DATE_REF={0}&STUDENT_ID={1}&ASSIGN_ID={2}"
     HeaderText="Edit" 
     Text="&lt;img src='/Images/edit.png' alt='Update' border='0'/&gt;" />
```

how could I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with Date Format String `{0:d}`,

```
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Edit.aspx?DATE_REF={0:d}&STUDENT_ID={1}&ASSIGN_ID={2}"
```

[Source](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/datanavigateurlformatstring-date-105982.aspx)